# iPad - Handling orientation change via reloaded loadView

Tags: uikit, ipad

I have a custom view which needs to be relaid on orientation change. My UIView code can correctly redraw for the any orientation as it express itself in screen frame size.

But how do I get the loadView method to run on orientation change for the right view to get drawn ?

I put   [self.view setNeedsDisplay] in the following rotation handling methods with no luck.

```
willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration
didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
```

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

`loadView` actually causes the view to be completely re-created from scratch. It should be sufficient to call `setNeedsDisplay` in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` *on the view that needs to redraw*.

If you have to change the layout of your views upon rotation, do so in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` (so the changes get animated), and/or set the `autoresizingMask` property to the combination of `UIViewAutoresizingMask` values that suits your needs.